How to assign keyframes to an empty object?
I have an Empty in 2D that acts as a control object for my character, but I can't animate it because it doesn't add keyframes.


We're gonna need more info here. What value are you trying to keyframe? Are you sure you're keyframing the right object? Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Keyframes are applied to the transformation values or other properties of the object.  Can you [edit] to provide more context?

What do you mean by an "empty in 2d"?

the whole movement of my 2d characters arm is parented to a circle.

There is no problem in adding keyframes to empties in your file. Moreover some of your empties already have initial keyframes.
But you were not able to see the keyframes added to empties, since the view mode was set to display only the Grease Pencil's keyframes.
To see keyframes assigned to empties you should switch the context from Grease Pencil to Dope Sheet.
This way:


Also I would like to remind, that since the 4.1 version of Blender, keyframes should be added in a slightly different way:

First press K - to select the keying mode (location/rotation/etc), also this will add the first keyframe.
Later, every time you need to add a keyframe, press I - to add a keyframe in the selected keying mode.

